# Angularjs ui.routing - add attribute to input elements before rendering HTML into ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `angular js - ui.router` concept for `SinglePageApplication` Development.

When I click Page 1 and Page 2 link, then its respective html page will be rendered into `'ui-view'` `div`. I want to add `'data-ng-blur'` attribute into respective html page(`Sample.html`, `Sample2.html`), input controls while click `'ui-sref'` link. I have give Document ready events in
that both htmls, But that's not fired. So there is any option for add attributes for input elements in loading html before its respective Controller called by `ui-router`.

```html
<div data-ng-app="ProjectApp">
<div class="menulist">
 <li><a ui-sref="pageone">Page 1</a></li>
 <li><a ui-sref="pagetwo">Page 2</a></li> 
</div>
 
<div class="ui-view"></div> 
 
<script>
 var loApp = angular.module("ProjectApp", ["ui.router"]);
loApp.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsenstiveMatch = true;
    
    $stateProvider
    .state('pageone', {
        url: '/Screen-one',
        templateUrl: 'Sample.html',
        controller: pageoneCtrler
    })
    .state('pagetwo', {
        url: '/Screen-two',
        templateUrl: 'Sample2.html',
        controller: pagetwoCtrler            
    });
});
 
loApp.controller("pageoneCtrler", function ($scope) {
 $scope.myfunction = function(){
  
 }
});
 
loApp.controller("pagetwoCtrler", function ($scope) {
 
});
 
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what should happen on `ng-blur`? You can call specific method in a controller like this: `ng-blur="myMethod()"`

Comment: yes, thats want i want. If i add attribute to html, in that respective controller, ng-blur not called while blur in input. So i want to add that ng-blur attribute before that controller called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of interceptor of $httpProvider i guess
$httpProvider.interceptors

Comment: Can you give any sample for this ..? I have googled this, but i cant get it clearly

Answer (score 0):

JQuery reference must be added before the angular js reference. If we add reference in this order, then document ready events fired of loaded htmls will be fired. Issue solved now.